# Packager too slow on macOS

Tags: react-native

Have an issue with packager. I'm always waiting for 20-25 min (even more) for transforming modules for first run, others transforms goes fast.

If i will close packager and do `react-native run-ios` after build i will get same issue to get it bundled ( will wait about 20-30min )

Tried re-install watchman, react-native cli - nothing helps i'm always waiting so long 
Also cleared cache - same problem

**Environment:**
iMac 2017 8gb
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
Node: 8.6.0
Yarn: 1.1.0
npm: 5.4.0
Watchman: 4.9.0
Xcode: Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235

**Packages:**
react-native: 0.42.0 
react: 15.4.1
Target Platform: iOS (11)

Comment: Slow internet? What do you mean by "other transforms"? Do you mean "subsequent before restarting the packager"?

Comment: @Eduard , Nope not internet 
"other transforms" i mean every new transform ( bundling when code was changed ) fast

Comment: Is there anything that helped you?

Comment: @HlebBarylskyi, nope :/ 
I found that only with one project i have this situation

Answer (score 0):

first of all it's so better to change your to 6.x.x and change your npm version to 4.6.1 and i have this issue too so this packager so much better works with yarn in my case, but you should know that it will take time for the first time but in my pc it took 10 mins